zip in ubuntu 24.04 getting buffer overflow if right single quote mark present
Using the zip command, I am sometimes getting the following error:
*** buffer overflow detected ***: terminated
Some file names in the material being backed up contain sight single quotation marks, (ascii code E2 80 99).  This is only a problem when using zip on ubuntu 24.04.  It works on ubuntu 22.04.
I don't understand how a fix gets into the software updater arena but I think (finally) for this issue and more importantly, the issue involving characters such as the german Umlaut ("ö") might be in the works.  The following just appeared in bug 2062535

** Merge proposal linked:    https://code.launchpad.net/~zhsj/ubuntu/+source/zip/+git/zip/+merge/475986


I find it hard to believe something like zip is failing like this, it's got to be something I'm doing however, if no one can give me a hint today I'll file a bug report then reference it here.

As a work-around:

Obtain an earlier version of zip. In my case, I took /usr/bin/zip from a Ubuntu 22.04
Set aside /usr/bin/zip, perhaps as /usr/bin/zip24
Put the older version of zip somewhere, in my case I placed it in /usr/local/bin/zip
Make a symbolic link at /usr/bin/zip pointing to the older version.
In my case the command (run from directory /usr/bin) was
ln -s /usr/local/bin/zip zip

Using this older version I generated a zip file which, unzipped on 24.04 compared exactly with the original material - in short it works.

I have filed bug 2066991 in bugs.launchpad.net for this problem.

ubuntu also has bug 2062535 which may be a similar situation.

Current status.  My bug, 2066991 has now been marked a duplicate of 2062535.  2062535 has now been marked priority high and status is Triaged. Fedora has a patch for it
https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/zip/raw/rawhide/f/buffer_overflow.patch.  No word yet on a fix for Ubuntu 24.04

What will happen when ubuntu releases a fix to zip?  Will the update replace the symbolic link created in /usr/bin or, will it follow the link and thus replace the temporary zip code placed at /usr/local/bin/zip

A comment has been added to bug 2062535, which is a similar situation.  While  we wait for the fix to be included in routine updates for ubuntu 24.04, consider the comment from the bug "found alternative 7z that has zip options
7z a -mx=0 zipname.zip filenameorfolder".  Personally, since I have brought in the 22.04 version of zip, I have not tested nor plan to use the 7z alternative.

Link to the Ubuntu bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zip/+bug/2062535

This may not be as rare as we'd hope.  In my case, it started failing the same day I cloned the Handbrake github source into a folder I backed up.  Traced it back and it is within that structure that the failure exposed itself to me.  Not saying everyone will have done this exactly, but again it's not an unusual activity.

In my case, zip was stumbling across a filename containing a german Umlaut ("ö"). I could rename the file and it came back to work.

It's good to see that you were able to get around the problem.  Such an approach would be applicable for small number uses.  Consider how this would be unmanageable when backing up a large number of files.  Just finding what the offending character(s) is would take too much time.  Some times a backup includes capture of webpages.  Attempts to rename files internal to a webpage capture presents additional, time consuming requirements.  In my opinion, this answer is not going to be practical.

There is a fixed version 3.0-14 in the Debian archives: https://packages.debian.org/trixie/zip
Edit: It is now also found on the Ubuntu 24.10 archives: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oracular/+source/zip
Just download the deb corresponding to your architecture and install it.

When will this be included in the usual apt upgrade for Ubuntu 24.04?

I can see 3.0-14 is already present in the archives for Ubuntu 24.10: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zip - Not sure if they are planning to backport it to 24.04, but you could do the upgrade yourself from the Ubuntu or Debian archives.

@JoseGómez Per vanadium 's answer to question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1517297/will-ubuntu-24-04-0-eventually-pick-up-all-fixes-etc-included-in-24-04-1 - it should roll into 24.04 and thus be picked up by the standard apt-get upgrade so no action will be required.

As of this morning's XUbuntu update, zip has not yet been updated.

So far it's only available in the Ubuntu Oracular (24.10) archives. But the deb itself works in 24.04 as well.

this works for my amd64 based 24.04 system:
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/740831076/zip_3.0-14_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i zip_3.0-14_amd64.deb

zip_3.0-14 did not fix it for me. And wouldn't launchpad issue 2062535 be updated? it hasn't been.

I downloaded zip_3.0-14_amd64.deb from the first link here and installed on my Ubuntu 24.04.1, it fixed my problem.

3.0.14 is still buggy for me, but 3.0.12build2 works.
