Will Ubuntu 24.04.0 eventually pick up all fixes etc. included in 24.04.1
I needed to roll forward to Ubuntu 24.04 this past May.  Many here suggest waiting for the first point release, possibly coming in August.  At some point after that point release comes out,  will those who took the initial Ubuntu 24.04.0 also be updated by the usual
apt-get upgrade

What exactly is the question?

Will the fixes of 24.04.01 be applied to 24.04.00 or would it be necessary to install 24.04.01 from scratch?

I think you’ll end up with the same system as if you’d waited until 24.04.01 - if you apply all updates.

It's the other way around - if you've been doing regular apt-get upgrades, then you have already got all the updates included in the point release.

You don't need to install anything from scratch. If you apply all updates to your 24.04.0 installation, at the moment when 24.04.1 is released your installation will be equal to 24.04.1.

As you update your 24.04.0 installation, it will acquire all updates and automatically become 24.04.1.
